# multiple different numbers of rows by ID to know if used or not

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to match the load amount used versus the total amount by each ID and flag it if used or not or partially used

**BEFORE**

```
df <- data.frame(id=c("101","101","102","102","102","102", "103", "103", "104", "104", "104", "104"),
          load=c(1889.46, 3239.27, 1253.81, 1253.81, 1103.81, 211.95, 1437.64,1437.64, 422.38, 300, 300, 300),
          used=c(5128.73, 5128.73, 3611.43, 3611.43, 3611.43, 3611.43, 1437.64,1437.64, 922.38, 922.38, 922.38, 922.38))
```

**RESULT**

for example in in ID 103 - in ID 103 lets say I used my credit card three days ago to purchase something of $200 and it was approved by my bank yesterday so that means I used $200 from my card and is paid for. Today I purchased another something again of $200 but is yet to be approved by my bank (still pending). So as a result i made two separate transaction of $200 but only the first is been paid. I hope this example is clear for other scenarios too?

```
result <- data.frame(id=c("101","101","102","102","102","102", "103", "103", "104", "104", "104", "104"),
      load=c(1889.46, 3239.27, 1253.81, 1253.81, 1103.81, 211.95, 1437.64,1437.64, 422.38, 300, 300, 300),
      used=c(5128.73, 5128.73, 3611.43, 3611.43, 3611.43, 3611.43, 1437.64,1437.64, 922.38, 922.38, 922.38, 922.38),
      result=c("paid","paid", "paid", "paid", "paid","not used", "used", "not used", "used", "used", "partially used", "not used"))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you clearly state how you categorize paid, not used, used and partially used?

Comment: for example in ID 101 a total amount 5,128.73 was used by a customer by different date. first transaction is 1889.46 which is less than the total paid of 5,128.73 so is paid and left with 3239.27 which match the last transaction

Comment: What is difference between `paid` and `used` ?

Comment: "used" is the total amount  in the card approved while "load" is each time transaction occurred (both pending and approved) and "result" shows paid in the result field  if first transaction is less than total amount used and you move to the second transaction if less than reminder of what left in first transaction loaded.

Comment: I mean in `result` column what is different between `paid` and `used`? Why is row 1 `paid` and row 9 `used` ?

Comment: Result is the outcome of "load" amount by "used". for example in ID 102. first transaction is 1251.81 and total used (approved) is 3611.43 so 1253.81 is less than total approved (used) so result should show paid. second transaction is 1253.81 and used will be left with 2357.62 so 12353.81 is less than 2357.62 and result should should paid  while the third transaction is 1103.81 and the remind less from 3611.43 based on the first two transaction is 1103.81. So the fourth transaction is left with nothin in used so is not used as a result

Comment: row 1  - the (two transactions) in load match the  used  while row 9 - the first three rows didnt match because the row 8 has already matched with used so row 9 has nothing left for that ID

Comment: Yes by why is the first line of 103 used and not paid?

Comment: in ID 103 lets say I used my credit card three days ago to purchase something of $200 and it was approved by my back yesterday so that means I used $200 from my card and is paid for. Today I purchased another something again of $200 but is yet to be approved by my bank (still pending). So as a result i made two seperate transaction of $200 but only the first is been paid. I hope this example is clear for other scenarios too?